# Customize the Paypal button in the Cart page of Shopify Website

Tags: iframe, paypal, shopify

I hope you are doing well.

I'm very very glad to jump here.

Would you please give me a hand for a while?

I would like to customize the Paypal button in the Cart page.

What's important here is that button is in the iframe.

Maybe if you know how to do it, please advise for me.

Thank you in advance.

Best Regards

I would like to customize the Paypal button.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the PayPal button is rendered by the PayPal JS SDK, similar to the demo at https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server , the only customization options are what the JS SDK provides for customization, as [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/multiparty/checkout/standard/customize/buttons-style-guide/) -- for example, there are a few colors and a pill shaped option.

Since the Shopify platform is rendering the button, only the options Shopify provides for changing its use of the JS SDK can be adjusted. I'm not aware of Shopify having any options at all for this, but that is what would theoretically possible.

Other things within the PayPal button iframe (besides what's documented in the JS SDK reference) cannot possibly be changed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The Paypal button is rendering inside the theme as a default function. At the moment, I'm using the Dawn theme. Then is it impossible?

Comment: As I explained, it's possible to change whichever of the PayPal JS SDK rendering options Shopify exposes for customization. They likely don't expose any, meaning nothing can be changed.

Comment: Yeah... seems like they didn't expose any...

Comment: These dynamic buttons are rendered using Shopify SDK and you can't update the look and feel of these buttons using CSS OR JS.

Comment: Gotcha... thank you Onkar!