# Dynamic buttons on the Dawn theme for Shopify

Tags: paypal, shopify

How can customize the PayPal button of the Dawn theme for Shopify?

I'm using the Dawn v11.0 and PayPal button is coming through iframe.
I was trying to update the style in the iframe but I'm not able to get the iframe element via javascript.

I would like to change the PayPal button's style

Comment: There are some options for customizing PayPal buttons rendered via the JS SDK, but it does not appear Shopify's integration with it exposes any of those options for you to change https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77341930/customize-the-paypal-button-in-the-cart-page-of-shopify-website